# Character encodings of strings in gradle

Tags: mysql, groovy, gradle

So in a gradle build, why would the Java string

`"foo"`  be acceptable to a mySQL database with UTF-8 encoding, but the GString
`"${someValue}"` would not be?

What's happening is this:

```
sql.withTransaction {
def batchResult = sql.withBatch(
  20,
  'insert into table(job_id, log_name, scenario_name, classification, value) values (?,?,?,?,?)'){  stmt ->
    rows.each  {  r ->
      def jobId = "${System.getenv('JOB_NAME')}:${System.getenv('BUILD_NUMBER')}"
      def classifier = "{'observer_id':${r['observer_id']}, 'sensor_name':${r['sensor_name']}}"

      stmt.addBatch(
               jobId,
               "foo",
               project.scenarioFilename,
               classifier,
               r['count(1)'])

    }
  }
```

This fails because the UTF-8 encoded database rejects the value of `jobId` (and `project.scenarioFilename`, and `classifier`), spewing some escaped characters like \xAC as unacceptable.

But what's funny is, if I do this

```
      stmt.addBatch(
        new String(jobIdStr.getBytes("UTF-16"),"UTF-8"),
        "foo",
        new String(project.scenarioFilename.getBytes("UTF-16"),"UTF-8"),
        new String(classifier.getBytes("UTF-16"),"UTF-8"),
        r['count(1)']
      )
```

it works.

So why is `"foo"` seen as UTF-8, but `"${System.getenv('JOB_NAME')}"` not?

Incidentally, setting `systemProp.file.encoding=utf-8` in `gradle.properties` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you try adding `.toString()` at the end of the GStrings : `"${..}:${..}".toString()`. I'm not sure if that will help, but have seen some problems with gstrings in groovy sql in past.

Comment: @kunal -- ```toString()``` does the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to not leave the question unanswered, i am putting this in answer.

Comment: What is the value of `jobId`, `project.scenarioFilename`, and `classifier`?

Comment: jobId is a gstring built from jenkins environment variables, scenarioFilename is a gstring built from file names on disk, and classifier is a gstring built up from several strings.  Maybe the solution is to simply not use gstrings at all and just use '+' with regular java strings.

Comment: I assume you have checked the _value_ of those strings and seen there is no unicode oddness going on though?  If what you say is the case, then `jobId.toString()` should fix it also.  Also, is it ALL of the variables, or just one of them causing the problem?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, I see the error on each value that was made with groovy string interpolation.  ```toString()``` worked for all three.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.toString()` at the end of the GStrings (`"${..}:${..}".toString()`) when using in groovy sql.